# Datatables last column disappears when shrinking screen

Tags: datatables

The last column disappears in datatabels when you resize the screen for mobile view. [example](http://www.gayshiz.com/)

Can anyone help me stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at your [stylesheet](http://www.gayshiz.com/css/style.css).

There is a rule at the end that makes the last column hide on mobile viewport.

Just remove this line and you'll probably be fine:

```
table.tablepress th.column-4,table.tablepress td.column-4{display:none;}
```